# Super+s not working

Tags: gnome, 22.10

I configured in settings->keyboard shortcuts Super+s to open settings.

The Problem:
It does nothing
While for example super+E works and opens the home folder

What now?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1993904). 'gnome-control-center' is the name of the GNOME Settings application. If you are logged in to launchpad, there is an option indicate that the bug affects you.